# PyMuPDFでPDFファイル内のリンクに関する情報を収集するプログラム

Tags: python, pdf

お世話になります。
PythonのPyMuPDFでPDFファイル内のリンクを貼っている部分と該当ページ、地の文を集めて、エクセルに出力するプログラムを作成していますが、`get_links()`ですべての要素が取ってこれるのかどうかわかりません。
初めて使うライブラリのため、GPT3.5にプログラムを生成させ、自分で修正してみていますがうまく行かない状況です。

```
def extract_links(pdf_path):
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)
    links_data = []

    for page_num in range(doc.page_count):
        page = doc[page_num]
        links = page.get_links()

        for link in links:
            if 'rect' in link:
                rect = fitz.Rect(link['rect'])
                link_data = {
                    'Link': link.get('uri', ''),
                    'Page': page_num + 1,
                    'Text': page.get_text('text', clip=rect)
                }
                links_data.append(link_data)

    doc.close()
    return links_data
```

一応リンクのあるページに当たると以下のように

```
In [66]: doc[7].get_links()[0]
Out[66]: 
{'kind': 1,
 'xref': 503,
 'from': Rect(385.8999938964844, 360.7300109863281, 449.0400085449219, 380.5299987792969),
 'page': 72,
 'to': Point(40.0, 323.0),
 'zoom': 0.0,
 'id': ''}
```

リンクの中身のようなものが帰ってきますが、プログラムの方はうまく作動しないです。
また、テキストの中身も取れていないような気がします。
環境はWin10, Python3.10です。

テスト用PDFとして
`https://phmpt.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/125742_S1_M5_c4591001-A-adrg.pdf`
を用いています。

詳しい方、解決策をご教示いただけますと幸いです。
PyMuPDF以外のパッケージでも構いません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4):

まず最初に、英語で答えることを許してください。

I am a maintainer of PyMuPDF. You may be pleased to read that its documentation now also is available in Japanese: https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/

To your question:
An item of `page.get_links()` is a dictionary. Its structure depends on the **kind** of the link. For example, kind 1 (`LINK_GOTO`) points to some place within the PDF. This is the case you are interested in it looks like. The dictionary for `LINK_GOTO` has the following keys:

```py
link = {
"kind": 1,  # = fitz.LINK_GOTO
"from": rect,  # the "hot area" on source page (reacts to mouse click)
"page": pno,  # (integer, 0-based) the target page number
"to": point,  # the target location on the target page
"zoom": factor,  # a float telling the viewer the magnification factor
}
```

As you will see, the target location is just the page number and a point on that page. There is no rectangle specified for the target. This is a PDF restriction, it has nothing to do with PyMuPDF.

Comment: これは良い回答です。しかし、本サイトが日本語版スタック・オーバーフローとして[日本語のナレッジを蓄積するという目標を持っている](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto)ことから、いずれ日本語へ翻訳された文章も併記される必要があるかもしれません。（時間ができたら翻訳したいので、わかりやすいようコメントを残しておきます）